# Can I filter and select only IPV4 adresses on the InetAddress object? How to exlude the IPV6?

Tags: java, inetaddress

I have the following problem: I create an ArrayList and I put in this arraylist all the IP addresses of my client (one if the client have a single network card, n if the client run on a PC having n network card) excluding the loopback adress, the point to point adress and the virtual adress.

I have do this in this way:

```
private static List<String> allIps = new ArrayList<String>();

static {
    Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nets;
    try {

        nets = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();


        while(nets.hasMoreElements()) {

            NetworkInterface current = nets.nextElement();

            if ((current.isUp()) && (!current.isPointToPoint()) && (!current.isVirtual()) && (!current.isLoopback())) {
                System.out.println(current.getName());
                Enumeration<InetAddress> ee = current.getInetAddresses();


                    while (ee.hasMoreElements()) {
                        InetAddress i = ee.nextElement();
                        System.out.println(i.getHostAddress());
                        allIps.add(i.getHostAddress());

                    }
            }
        }
    } catch (SocketException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("List of all IP on this client: "
            + allIps.toString());
    System.out.println("Number of ip: " + allIps.size());

}
```

It seems work well, the only problem is that my output (in the Eclipse console) is:

```
eth0
fe80:0:0:0:20c:29ff:fe15:3dfe%2
192.168.15.135
List of all IP on this client: [fe80:0:0:0:20c:29ff:fe15:3dfe%2, 192.168.15.135]
Number of ip: 2
```

Using the debugger and the console output appear clear to me that, in this case, **the only network interface** present is **eth0** (and this is ok) but, for this network interface, id found 2 IP adresses (the fits one is IPV6 address, the second one is the classic IPV4 address)

So it put in my adresses list **allIps** both.

I want select and put in my **allIps** list only the **IPV4** adresses and not also the IPV6. What can I do to do it? Can I filter and select only IPV4 on my **InetAddress** object?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 13):

Use `instanceof` and the [Inet4Address](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Inet4Address.html) type:

```
for (NetworkInterface ni :
                     Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())) {
  for (InetAddress address : Collections.list(ni.getInetAddresses())) {
    if (address instanceof Inet4Address) {
      System.out.println(address);
    }
  }
}
```